# Any suggestions for an automated way to capture your application's external connections?

Tags: java, security, connection, monitoring, dynatrace

I am trying to replace a requirement our dev teams have where they manually have to fill out a form that includes a list of their app's external connections (for example any database connections, calls to other services/applications, backing services, etc...). This is required in order to get approval to deploy to production. Mgmt/Security and our last mile folks use this information to determine risk level and to make sure that any scheduled dependencies are looked at (e.g., make sure the deployment is not scheduled for a time when one of the backing services is down so all the integration tests don't fail). Any suggestions to capture this automatically by scanning the code in Git? Or can Dynatrace provide this information if we have it monitoring in the lower environments pre-prod?  Some other tool?

A little background in case you need it - we are using Jenkins with OpenShift to deploy docker containers to AWS PaaS. Code is stored in Git, we use Bitbucket. In the pipeline we have SonarQube scanning and a tool that scans third party libraries the app is using (e.g., struts, cucumber, etc..). We have dynatrace to monitor the app in production (but we can also use it in dev if we want). Mostly Java apps but we also have Node and Python and .NET.

Comment: Best-case szenario, the configuration should be fully externalized and you can just send them a (sanitized) `application.properties`/`application.yml`. Bonus points if Ops is able to set said configuration through environment variables. You should not have any production-settings checked-in to git.

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest a way to automate this.  I suspect there isn't one.

I would have thought it was advisable that the dev teams did this by hand anyway.  Surely they should have a handle on what external connections the apps *ought to be* making.  Expecting the production / security team to take care of it all means that they need to develop a deeper understanding of the app's functionality and architecture so that they can make a reasoned decision on whether particular access is necessary,

I do have one suggestion though.  You could conceivably do your testing on machines with firewalls that block out-going connections for all but a set of white-listed hosts and ports.  That white-list could be the starting point for the forms you need to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into tagging? Manual or environment based variable set up looks painful (which is why I have avoided), but might be worthwhile? https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/tags-and-metadata/